# Is there a way to update linked pictures from another workbook without having to open it?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report dashboard in WB1 that has linked pictures of charts from another workbook WB2 (PASTE/SPECIAL PASTE/LINKED PICTURE)

The sales team is updating WB2 and linked pictures in WB1 do not update unless both workbooks are open.

So I had a work around by implementing a button in WB1 to open and close WB2 and that updated the links.

Now for some reason that stopped working. The only change I did was change the WB2 into a workbook with a macro (it now auto updates all graphs when new values are added).

```
Sub Gumb214_Klikni()
'Button to open and close WB2
   Dim xWb As Workbook
   Dim wbName As String
   On Error Resume Next
   Set xWb = Workbooks.Open("path to link")
   wbName = xWb.Name
   Workbooks("name of folder").Close
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "This workbook does not exist!", vbInformation, "ERROR"
     Err.Clear
   Else
    MsgBox "TEXT"
  End If
End Sub
```

The catch is that even if I return to the old way to a non macro WB2 the button stopped refreshing the picture links and they are only refreshed it you manually open them or have both workbooks open.

Is there any other way to update linked pictures? This is driving me nuts since it worked fine before I tried to save time and auto refresh WB2 graphs.

Comment: No you'll need to open it to update them. What you can do though is open the destination workbook in another instance of Excel which you can make hidden from the user making it look like no workbook was opened

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment. Updating them this way will make it look seamless to the end user and give the false impression that the destination workbook wasn't 'opened'

```
Sub Gumb214_Klikni()
    'Button to open and close WB2
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim wbName As String


    On Error Resume Next
    With xlApp
        .Visible = False
        Set xWb = .Workbooks.Open("path to link")
    End With
    wbName = xWb.Name
    Workbooks("name of folder").Close
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "This workbook does not exist!", vbInformation, "ERROR"
        Err.Clear
    Else
        ' Update pictures here via whatever method and save&close the destination workbook
        MsgBox "TEXT"
    End If

    ' Quit the second instance of the application
    With xlApp
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the imput.
I am getting an error that the file doesnt exsist even tho I have filled in the relative paths. Is there a way to update my macro to open WB2 as hidden and close it when WB1 closes?

Comment: You'll need to use the absolute path for opening the workbook.

Comment: What does that mean exactly? I am using the full path for the file on the server that works with my original macro.

Comment: Ah apologies. Relative path is to a location where as the absolute path is what you’ve described. You’ll need to check your file path. Try opening the workbook and executing `Activeworkbook.Fullname` on it and make sure the paths match

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox ActiveWorkbook.FullName
End Sub

This returns the same path that I am using. So I have no idea why I keep getting the error file not found.

Comment: I'd suggest stepping through your code with F8 and checking all values